# Passed variable is not an array or object

Tags: migrations

Trying to migrate images by copying them from an external source:

```
id: custom_news_migration_with_external_images_1
label: custom news migration with external images importer
source:
  plugin: embedded_data
  ids:
    id:
      type: integer
  constants: file_destination: /home/ip/c921/web/sites/default/files/images #absolute path ... default 'public://images'
process:
  nid: id
  title: title
  field_news_image:
    plugin: image_import
    source: file
    destination: 'constants/file_destination'
    title: file_title
    alt: title
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  default_bundle: news
```

The error I continually get in the console is:

> [error]  ... Passed variable is not an array or object in /home/ip/c921/web/core/modules/migrate/src/Plugin/migrate/source/EmbeddedDataSource.php Zeile 96

Code snippet:

```
     92   /**
     93    * {@inheritdoc}
     94    */
     95   public function initializeIterator() {
     96     return new \ArrayIterator($this->dataRows);
     97   }
```

Forgot to mention that the drupal.org example has data_rows entries:

```
  data_rows:
    -
      id: 1
      title: 'Page 1 title'
      file: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/druplicon-small.png'
      file_title: 'Druplicon logo'  
    -
      id: 2
      title: 'Page 2 title'
      file: 'https://www.drupal.org/files/drupal_logo-blue.png'
      file_title: 'Drupal logo'
```

I didn't use them. Because I want to migrate thousends of images.

[The basic example is from drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/migrate-api/migrate-destination-plugins-examples/migrating-files-and-images)

Help would be great.

Comment: Can you update your question with sample source data?

Comment: Aren't you missing the data_rows entry in your .yml config file? I may be wrong but I'd try to write a script to populate the .yml file data_rows entry with the thousands of image references.